Sporadic swap failures in Azure Function
We are running Azure Functions using .Net 8 as Isolated Process with two slots: production and staging. We first deploy to staging and then swap it to production though we have started observing very slow and some times even swaps that fails. I have been able to find an error that reoccurs in Deployment Center:
Unexpected internal error:
System.ServiceModel.Web.WebFaultException`1[Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.ErrorEntity]: 
Bad Request (Fault Detail is equal to Code: BadRequest, ExtendedCode: 
HttpContext.Current is null object is not present in the request body., Message: 01008).

This is my best indication that something goes wrong as I can't see anything in Application Insights. I have been trying hard to identify where the exception might occur but I can not see any references to HttpContext.Current in our codebase.

I am also experiencing this error and cannot associate it with any of our code. strange.
It does appear that error is the sign of a problem during slot swaps, when we are experiencing failures that error appears and it happens on different App Services.
I see your answer Pravallika, but this is an intermittent issue and not introduced by a code change from us as I see it.
(unable to write this as a comment on your original post)
UPDATE: I found this issue in github, a bit older but may help you
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/8448

We ended up deleting the App Service Plan and starting over which seems to have helped. I know this is not really a viable solution but it was OK for us since it was just the dev environment. I saw the GitHub issue too as they refer to it from the Azure Portal with a mention of it being "resolved soon" despite the issue is several years old.

I resolved it by switching the app service plan to another size and then back

The slow swap happens if your functions are taking a long time to warm up after the swap due to large number of dependencies.

Update the dependencies.
Deploy the functions as a package file.


HttpContext.Current is null object is not present in the request body

The error could be due to the issue with the request body, such as an invalid request or a missing parameter.

Check if HttpContext is null.

I have created a .NET 8.0 isolated Azure Function.
Application Settings of the function app:


Deployed the function to Staging Slot of Azure function app.

Staging Slot:



Able to swap the function from Staging slot to Production slot of the function app.


Production Slot:


Able to run the function of Production slot:


